# Running “New Query” crashes SQL Server Management Studio 2019 on Windows 10

Tags: crash, windows-10, ssms, restart, sql-server-2019

When I tried to run a query in SSMS 18.6 it froze for few seconds and after it restarted, not working to run the query.

Answer (score 3):

I opened my sql server managemens studio 18.6 version (ssms) and tried to runa  query on a table, and after few seconds, restarted, without running the query.

My solution was running the ssms as ADMINISTRATOR

Answer (score 0):

I have SSMS 19.0.1 and have the same problem.
Crashes can be resolved either by running SSMS as ADMINISTRATOR or by following the instructions in the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/282990/ssms-crash-after-one-sql-query-window-pull-to-anot

Or you can try Azure Data Studio, it has some things better thought out than SSMS but also several shortcomings in terms of stored procedures and functions.

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions on the C:Windows\temp file - apparently the 22H2 release of Windows 10 changed those permissions, and SSMS tries to open and do other operations on that folder.  We just pinned this down with MS after running Procmon and seeing access denied errors from SSMS in the event logs.  Certainly explains why running as Admin fixes it.